# Opening a write stream causes a seperate read stream to do nothing

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, stream

Running the below code works perfectly, the chunks are logged, no error message is given, and when the stream is over, ended is logged.

```
stdout.on 'error', (error) ->
  console.log error

stdout.on('data', (chunk) ->
  console.log(chunk)
)

stdout.on('end', ->
  console.log("Ended")
  callback error, null
)
```

Here's where a really odd problem happens. I add one line

```
writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('image.jpeg')

stdout.on 'error', (error) ->
  console.log error

stdout.on('data', (chunk) ->
  console.log(chunk)
)

stdout.on('end', ->
  console.log("Ended")
  callback error, null
)
```

And as soon as a define the writeStream, nothing happens at all on the stdout, no errors are logged, no chunks, no ended. Nothing :(

**Context**

The general flow of my application to get to this state is a client makes a API call to the server, the server grabs the image from local storage and runs it through a popular node js library called graphicsmagick, which transforms the image dimensions and in my case gives it back as a stream to stdout.

Normally i simply pipe stdout back to the user and give them there resized image but this time i wanted to try and use a write stream to save the resized file.

**More Context**
As soon as i open a write stream, everything dies, i define a write stream at the top of my file, and debugging lower in the file ceases to output. The client receives a 502 error response from the server

Comment: I think you're going to have to show more code, especially two separate code snippets: one that works and one that doesn't. It's currently not clear what you're doing where. Calling `fs.createWriteStream()` is not going to magically interfere with stdout or anything else.

Comment: That's the thing it does. I'll show the two full code blocks. But the file this is in is hundreds of lines so i can't just copy the whole thing.